# Line and column cannot be determined in macro sas

Tags: macros, sas

```
%macro pesee(nom, imprec, poids, nb_simul);
data &nom.;
do i=1 to &nb_simul.;
PoidsR= RAND('UNIForm', &poids.*(1- &imprec.), &poids.*(1+ &imprec.));
output;
end;
run;
%mend;
%pesee(Sucre, 0.1,200,3);
```

Hi there, 
I am launching the macro simulation, but all the time it gives the following error `Line and column cannot be determined`.

Comment: Hello, code was executed on 9.4 , and I have no errors or warnings. Can you add `options mprint mlogic symbolgen;` before your code& may be it'shelpto find error.

Comment: start a new session and run again. it works for me too

Comment: Show more of your code, before and after, and if it is called from within another macro.

Comment: Hi; "Line and column cannot be determined" is not an error in and of itself.  It's an accompaniment to another error, and just says that SAS can't tell you inside an executing macro what line of the log it's on as the macro generates its own lines.  What other errors do you see in the log?

Comment: Dear friends, yes, after the restart of the program the macro worked. THank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you do not have SAS 9.4 (or perhaps even have an older version of 9.4).  The additional options to the RAND distribution for UNIFORM I believe were added in SAS 9.4 TS1M5 (though I can't find evidence it was added in that specific maintenance release, and it may have been possible prior in a preproduction state, it wasn't in the [9.3 documentation](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p0fpeei0opypg8n1b06qe4r040lv.htm) and they made lots of changes to RAND in 9.4 TS1M5); prior to that no arguments were possible to UNIFORM.

You most likely have to do this:

```
%macro pesee(nom, imprec, poids, nb_simul);
data &nom.;
do i=1 to &nb_simul.;
PoidsBase= &poids. + (2*&imprec.)*RAND('UNIForm') - &imprec.;
output;
end;
run;
%mend;
%pesee(Sucre, 0.1,200,3);
```

This produces the identical results to the above when a `call streaminit` line is added to get a fixed seed (which I *highly* recommend).